# Convert the first letter to Capital letter but ONLY for UPPERCASE strings - PHP

Tags: php

Anyone could help me doing this?

For example I have a string of

```
SOME of the STRINGS are in CAPITAL Letters
```

What I want exactly for the output is

```
Some of the Strings are in Capital Letters
```

Only those in UPPERCASE will be turn their first letter to capital and leave the rest as lower case.

How can I achieve this using PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh cmon, you can do some research into regular expressions and string functions and give it a shot.

Comment: yeah okay. What's stackoverflow for? -_-Thanks anyway

Comment: It is for getting help on a problem you have already tried yourself to solve. What you have there is no attempt at all at solving the issue.

Comment: Sorry to say but I tried it and I can't so I seek for help. Don't be a nice guy, it's not suited to you :D. Please research what is "Ask Question" button does too. Thanks anyway, it was solved already. Thanks to the other guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, really helpful and it gives me ideas.
I use preg_replace as well, just sharing to those who might need it too.

```
preg_replace('/([A-Z])([A-Z ]+)/se', '"\\1" . strtolower("\\2")', $str);
```

OR

```
preg_replace('/([?!]{2})([?!]+)/', '\1', $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `preg_replace_callback` to find all uppercase words an replace them with a custom callback function

Answer (score 3):

Quick example:

```
$input = "SOME of the STRINGS are in CAPITAL Letters";
$words = explode(" ",$input);
$output = array();
foreach($words as $word)
{
    if (ctype_upper($word)) $output[] = $word[0].strtolower(substr($word,1));
    else $output[] = $word;
}
$output = implode($output," ");
```

Output:

> Some of the Strings are in Capital Letters

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtolower` and `ucwords`

```
$word = "SOME of the STRINGS are in CAPITAL Letters";
echo ucwords(strtolower($word));
```

Output

```
Some Of The Strings Are In Capital Letters
```

If you want it exactly the way you described

```
$word = "SOME of the STRINGS are in CAPITAL Letters";
$word = explode(" ", $word);
$word = array_map(function ($word) {return (ctype_upper($word)) ?  ucwords(strtolower($word)) : $word;}, $word);
echo implode(" ", $word);
```

Output

```
 Some of the Strings are in Capital Letters
```

Comment: sorry to say but the output is 
"Some Of The Strings Are In Capital Letters"

Comment: "Only those in UPPERCASE will be turn their first letter to capital and leave the rest as lower case."

Comment: the second one seems good. But you need to map the lower case ones first. anyways thanks

Comment: Thanks .. added improved version to output "Some of the Strings are in Capital Letters"

Comment: Note: This function removes existing capitalization, for example, the word "Letters" becomes "letters".

Answer (score 1):

if you want to avoid regular expressions

```
$text = "SOME of the STRINGS are in CAPITAL Letters";

$str_parts = explode(" ", $text);

foreach ($str_parts as $key => $str_part)
{
  if (ctype_upper($str_part) == strtolower(substr($str_part,1)))
  {
    $str_parts[$key] = ucfirst(strtolower($str_part));;
  }
}

$text = implode($str_parts, " ");

echo $text;
```